# Hadoop 2.7 - Simple Java code to create directory in HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, mapreduce

All I am trying is to create a directory in HDFS using Java programmatically.
I am getting this error.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem could not be instantiated

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/AmazonServiceException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException

Not sure where all these Amazon S3 came over here. Please help.

Here's the code. This is Hadoop 2.7

```
package tas.module1;


import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.BlockLocation;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;


public class JavaClient {

public JavaClient() {

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    JavaClient jc = new JavaClient();
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
       config.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"));
       config.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml"));

       config.set("fs.hdfs.impl", 
                org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName()
            );
           config.set("fs.file.impl",
                org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName()
            );
      FileSystem dfs = FileSystem.get(config);
      String dirName = "TestDirectory";
      System.out.println(dfs.getWorkingDirectory() +" this is from /n/n");
      Path src = new Path(dfs.getWorkingDirectory()+"/"+dirName);

       dfs.mkdirs(src); 



System.out.println("created dir");

    dfs.close();

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ah, this is a bug fixed a while back in [HADOOP-12636](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12636), which relates to the java service API and classpaths. Hadoop 2.7.2 enumerates all available filesystem implementation classes in JARs, and fails here due to the transient classpath problems.

If you drop the hadoop-aws JAR from your CP this will go away, or just upgrade to Hadoop 2.7.3

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing some dependency related to the working with S3 file system. In order to work with it, you need to have aws java sdk jars deployed in your cluster. You can download aws-java-sdk from http://sdk-for-java.amazonwebservices.com/latest/aws-java-sdk.zip. Then you need to unzip it, and copy every jar in aws-java-sdk/lib/ and aws-java-sdk/third-party/ to your datanodes.

Another option is to create uber jar and include this dependency directly into your jar through maven:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.91</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply.
The issue is why I am getting this AWS S3 related error message because my hadoop pseudo cluster is local and all I am trying is to create a folder in HDFS using java program.

My Hadoop is in local VM in Ubuntu 14.